# What kind of high level semantic free GIS layers out there?

Tags: data, land-cover

I'm looking for free GIS data that contains some high level information such as type of vegetation or type of soil or some other visual characteristics of the neighborhoods. I need more information than Google/Bing/Yahoo Maps. Do you know any GIS server that has this kind of information in it?

Thanks,

Comment: Yo should specify from what area are you looking the information

Comment: @phoenix7, Can you elaborate more what you mean by, "other visual characteristics of the neighborhoods"?

Comment: I need this for research purposes. Actually, I looking for the whole earth. But if it is only available for some parts of the world it's still good for me.

Answer (score 3):

Within the US you can obtain detailed soil data from [NRCS](http://websoilsurvey.sc.egov.usda.gov/).  For vegetation, check out the [GAP](http://www.nbii.gov/portal/server.pt/community/maps_and_data/1850) data.

Comment: Thanks @artwork21. I'm looking for some visual characteristics (like the one that you mentioned GAP). Some examples could be type of vegetation, perhaps types of buildings, etc. Do you know any thing else similar to GAP?